# Stuck when I call a method that is returned an array

Tags: java

I am very new to programming so if you don't judge me I'd be happy. I am trying to my homework and I got stuck on one question.

```
public static int[] decimalToBinary(int number) {
    int[] binary = new int[9];
    int remainder = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < binary.length) {
        remainder = number % 2;
        binary[binary.length - i - 1] = remainder;
        number /= 2;
        i++;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

I use this method as a helper method.

```java
public static char[][] headsNtails(int number) {
    int counter = 0;
    int[] array = decimalToBinary(number);
    int[][] decimalCoins = new int[3][3];
    for(int i = 0; i < decimalCoins.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < decimalCoins.length; j++) {
            decimalCoins[i][j] = array[counter];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    char[][] charCoins = new char[3][3];
    for(int i = 0; i < charCoins.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < charCoins.length; j++) {
            if(decimalCoins[i][j] == 1)
                charCoins[i][j] = 'T';
            else
                charCoins[i][j] = 'H';
        }
    }
    return charCoins;
}
```

When I call `headsNtails` method, in `main`, to display the char array, nothing happens. I don't get an error but when I debug, I saw that the program gets stuck when I call `decimalToBinary` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] charArray2D = headsNtails(7);
    display2D(charArray2D);
}
```

My `main` method is something like that. `display2D` is a method to display all characters in 2D array.

```
public static void display(int[] array) {
    for (int i : array) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t", i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void display2D(char[][] array2D) {
    for (char[] row : array2D) {
        display(row);
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
}

public static void display(double[] array) {
    for (double i : array) {
        System.out.printf("%.1f\t", i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void display(int[] array) {
    for (int i : array) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t", i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void display(char[] array) {
    for (int i : array) {
        System.out.printf("%c\t", i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? How do you call it? What *do* you expect to happen? Not having read your code in detail I don't see a `System.out.println()` or anything else that would output any visible feedback to you. What does your `main` method look like? My guess is that you call `headsNtails` but ignore the return value.

Comment: I don't see any reason why the `decimalToBinary()` method presented would hang or take much time to run.

Comment: I posted my main method.

Comment: when I say nothing happens It means there is no output . It is supposed to display all the characters.

Comment: Please post the complete code. It is hard to guess what `display2D` method is doing here.

Comment: just because your method is named "displayX" doesn't mean it'll display something

Comment: have you debugged your code to see whether what you pass is that what you think you pass?

Comment: I think I shared all the codes. Sorry for not being specific enough.

Comment: When I debug, int[] array = decimalToBinary(number);  It stops here It won't pass.

Comment: what is the value of number there? if it is a valid int, and it just "stops there", you may have forgotten to re-compile your code after adjusting it

Comment: In main method I use 7 for value of number. If you meant that.

Comment: you are looping over your 2D char array wrong. You need a nested for loop. Also the `display` method should expect char array instead of `int[]`.

Comment: Actually, display method is overloaded so there is a display(char[] array) method too. But when I click the display method It showed that it takes int[] parameters so I posted it int display.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to loop over a 2D array, you will need a nested for loop. The first loop will iterate over the `rows` and the second on the `columns`.
So for example here is how you will rewrite your `display2D` method.

```
public static void display2D(char[][] array2D) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < array2D[i].length; j++) {
            display(array2D[i]);
  }
}
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
}
```

Also note that your `display` method is expecting a `char` array so you need to change the parameter from `int[]` to `char[]`

Comment: I changed my display2D method to yours and run it. Still same thing happened. I dont think display methods are wrong because they were given ready, I didnt write them. So if there was a problem with them, other students would have mentioned .

Comment: Please update your question with your overloaded `display` methods.

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: I tried to run your code. Check it [here](http://tpcg.io/_XA4BVN)

Comment: Does the program run properly for you? When I execute, it is not.

Comment: Regardless of the correctness of the output, it does display it. You can run it in this online editor by pressing execute on the top right corner.

Comment: Still, I didnt get why Eclipse behave like that. By the way, In online editor, the output always changes. There is a strange problem in my code but couldnt find it.